# Knockout options conditional css

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have an observable array of objects

```
question = {
        ownerUserName: item.id,
        text: item.text,
        dataType: item.dataType,
        personalized: item.personalized,
        status: item.status,
        actionUserName: item.actionUserName
    }
```

And a select with options from this array:

```
<select id="questId" style="width: 425px" data-bind="options: questionList, optionsText: 'text'">
```

How with the help of knockout can I make so that if question.personalized == "Y" color of the text of this question would be green?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is the [css binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html)

A quick adaptation of the documentation to your need would be

```
<div data-bind="text: personalized, css: personalizedStatus">
   Profit Information
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    question.personalizedStatus = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.personalized() == "Y" ? "green" : "red";
    }, question);

</script>
<style>
    .green {color:green;}
    .red{color:red;}
</style>
```

Comment: I should create a question model?

Comment: To be honest I am not sure. i just tried to adapt the example to your code sample. I would create a question model just for ease of use.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **foreach** instead of usual **options** binding. Something like

```
<style>
   .highlighted{
      background-color: red;
   }
</style
<select id="questId" style="width: 425px" data-bind="foreach: questionList">
   <option data-bind="text: text, class: {highlighted: personalized == 'Y'}">
</select>
```

Comment: are you sure about this code:  class: {highlighted: personalized == 'Y'}, because it's not working. attr : {class : "highlighted"} will work, though, but it doesn't meet my requirments

Comment: @Skeeve
I'm using this code in my own projects and it works. The only thing is if 'personalized' is observable, then you should write `personalized() == 'Y'`

Answer (score 1):

There is also option to set data-bind="style:{color: value ? 'green' : null}"

It's not the best option (the best is to set new class) but it's possible